# Node/Firebase : Firebase not updating

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I have this React function that uses google fonctions to update user info on firebase :

```
export function updateUserData(token, newUserData, snackbar) {
  return function(dispatch) {
      const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}\`,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      };
      console.log("Post")
      return fetch(`
        https: //app.cloudfunctions.net/app/user`, {
          headers,
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(newUserData)
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
      snackbar("Successfully updated your data!", "success")
      dispatch({
        type: `USERDATA`,
        data: newUserData
      })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      snackbar("Failed to update. Try again later.", "error")
      console.log(`There was an error posting data: ${err}`)
    });
  };
}
```

The user info is void before I execute the code. Once I execute it, the POST request fail with :

`error  Object { code: 5, details: "No document to update: projects/app/databases/(default)/documents/users/tUCKX8CfXkh7onvQ9jlDnR50cpB3/private/tUCKX8CfXkh7onvQ9jlDnR50cpB3", note: "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient", … }`

Note : This is my first post so idk what information I should give

I tried modifying the database, with no change.